# Accessing c++ object data members from R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Apologies if this is a silly question as I am not a c++ or Rcpp expert but is it possible to access c++ data members from R? My attempt below fails:

test.cpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class myclass {
private:
  int k;
public:
  myclass(int &n) : k(n){}
  int getk() const {return k;}
};

typedef myclass* pmyclass;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<pmyclass> new_myclass(NumericVector n_) {
  int n = as<int>(n_);
  myclass x(n);
  return(XPtr<pmyclass>(new pmyclass(&x)));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector getk(SEXP xpsexp){
  XPtr<pmyclass> xp(xpsexp);
  pmyclass x = *xp;
  return wrap(x -> getk());
}
```

test.R

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp('./cpp_attempt/live_in_cpp/minimal_fail/test.cpp')

ptr <- new_myclass(10)

getk(ptr)
#19274768
```

Comment: Yes you can, using either Rcpp Modules, or via external pointers (though your example is not quite correct) or of course manually with getter and setter function to an instance of your class (for which you also need a ctor ticked from R).

Comment: I will look at Rcpp Modules. After a quick glance it looks as if your https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-modules.pdf documentation covers it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes look at the example inside of Rcpp (and its tests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class myclass {
private:
  int k;
public:
  myclass(int n) : k(n){}
  int getk() const {return k;}
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP new_myclass(int n) {
  XPtr<myclass> ptr(new myclass(n), true);
  return ptr;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int getk(SEXP xpsexp){
  XPtr<myclass> xp(xpsexp);
  return xp->getk();
}
```

Comment: Yep, was going to post exactly this after noticing my mistake (by cross-referencing with Dirk's pdf). Thank you.